# Returning data from AJAX in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

My lecturer gave me a project for me and my friend, creating an app using newest Laravel framework. I'm not to familiar with this framework. I'm trying to load a data to my view using AJAX.

[User Navigation for searching customer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6ZGP.png)

This is the code for displaying the table

```
@foreach($mpelanggan as $mpelanggan)
    {{ Form::open() }}
    {{ Form:: hidden('_method' ,'DELETE')}}
         <tr>
            <p hidden id="kd" value="{{$mpelanggan->Kd_Pelanggan}}"/>
            <td>{{$mpelanggan->Perusahaan}}</td>
            <td align="center">
                <button type="button" class="btntransparant" value="{{$mpelanggan->Perusahaan}}" id="ch">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
            <a class="fontblack" >
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a> &nbsp
            <button type="submit" class="btntransparant" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this data?');">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
{!!Form::close()!!}
@endforeach
```

When user click the + button it will load the list of his transaction in this table:

[Customer Transaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0Tdj.png)

**My Routes:**

```
Route::get('trans','TransController@index');
Route::get('getBTB',array('as'=>'getBTB','uses'=>'TransController@getBTB'));
```

**My Controller TransController:**

```
public function index(){
 $Mpelanggan = Mpelanggan::all();
 return view('tr.nav')->with('mpelanggan' , $Mpelanggan);
}


public function getBTB(Request $request){
  $term = $request->term;
  $data = Trbtb_h::where('Kd_Pelanggan',$term)->get();
  $result=array();
  foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $result[]=['No_BTB'=>$value->No_BTB,'Tgl_BTB'=>$value->Tgl_BTB];
  }
 return Response::json(array('success'=>true,'result'=>$result));
}
```

**The AJAX**

```
        $('#ch').click(function(){
         var np=$(this).attr('value');
         var get=$('#table1 > tbody');
         $('#btb-title').text(np);
         $("#pnl-btb").show();
         $("#pnl-faktur").show();
         $("#pnl-bayar").show();
         $("#pnl-btb-list").show();
         $.ajax({
            url         :'getBTB',
             type       :'GET',
             dataType   :'JSON',
             success    :'success',
             data       :{'term':kd},
             success    :function(result){
                 var data = JSON.parse(result);
                 var x;
                 for(x=0;x<data.length;x+=1){
                     var dat = data[i];
                     get.append('<tr><td>'+dat.No_BTB+'</td><td>'+dat.Tgl_BTB+'</td><td align="center"><button type="button" class="btntransparant" value="" id="ch"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button> <a class="fontblack" > <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> </a> &nbsp<button type="submit" class="btntransparant><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a></td></tr>');
                 }
             }
         })
        });
```

I want to put the data from $result in the btody tag, just like the customer list table.

```
    <div class="row" id="pnl-faktur">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="table2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Plh</th>
                    <th>No. Faktur</th>
                    <th>Tanggal</th>
                    <th>Jatuh Tempo</th>
                    <th>Piutang</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <td colspan="4" align="right">Total</td>
                <td><input type=text/></t>
            </tfoot>
    </div>
```

I watched some tutorial about AJAX and Laravel but none that I understand, I dont know what to do to load the $result to my view in the AJAX script.
This is my first question in stackoverflow, if i made any mistake im sorry

Comment: Need to parse the json data to html inside an ajax success handler

Comment: @charlietfl then i loop like this? 
var data = JSON.parse(result);
 var x;
 for(x=0;x< data.length;x+=1){
  var dat = data[i];} ?

Comment: Basically ... yes. Note that since you use `dataType:'json'` it will already be parsed array

Comment: I already updated my code, so if im not mistaken i can get the array attribute by using `dat.Atribute_name` right?  @charlietfl i tried to run it but it says jquery.min.js:6 GET http://localhost:8000/getBTB?result 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: You aren't sending key/value pair in url params. Try `data           :{'term':'someValue'}`

Comment: Oh I see, i already add to the code by sending the id to the requested url, but still getting internal 500 error:  jquery.min.js:6 GET http://localhost:8000/getBTB?term=XX111 500 (Internal Server Error) is it my model or my DB? @charlietfl

Comment: Don't know...you need to use some server side error reporting and inspect actual response in browser dev tools network to see what output message tells you

Comment: thanks a bunch btw you help me understand this way more better, i'll check error report then @charlietfl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is I access the wrong array from the success function. So my friend advice me to split it into 2 different variable in the controllers

**AJAX**

```
  $.ajax({
     url        :'getBTB',
     type       :'GET',
     dataType   :'json',
     success    :'success',
     data       :{'term':kd},
     success    :function(result){
         $.each(result.result, function(i,index){
             $('#table4 tbody').append('blablabla');
         });
     }
```

**Controller**

```
public function getBTB(Request $btbid){
  $term = $btbid->term;
  $data = Trbtb_h::where('Kd_Pelanggan',$term)->get();
  $sen['success'] = true;
  $sen['result'] = $data->toArray();
  return Response::json( $sen );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    $arr=[];
    $arr['javob'] = "ok";   
    $arr['scan_necessary'] = $scan_necessary;
    return response()->json($arr, 204);
```